# IsolatedStorageFileStream to base64

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I am trying to convert a file to a base64 string.
This is my code:

```
   IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(Filename, FileMode.Create, myIsolatedStorage);
   fileStream.Write(stream.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)stream.Position);

   byte[] binaryData = new Byte[fileStream.Length];
   long bytesRead = fileStream.Read(binaryData, 0, (int)fileStream.Length);
   string fileBase64 = System.Convert.ToBase64String(binaryData, 0, binaryData.Length);
   text1.Text = fileBase64.ToString();
```

but in text1 textblock, I get this string: "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA..."

Why ?

Comment: Why are you using `IsolatedStorageFileStream` at all?

Comment: because I need to save the file in the isolated storage and then convert it in a base64 string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to rewind `fileStream` before you read the data you just wrote.

Set its `Position` to `0`.

Comment: how can I rewind filestrem ?

Comment: Set its `Position` to `0`.